# Normalize across DB then across Group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, normalize

I'm trying to normalize continuous variables first across the entire DF, then normalize again within group.

Here is a sample DF

```
       ave_win_last5  id_race
0               6.00     6734
1               3.25     6734
2               6.75     6734
3               5.50     6734
4               5.50     6734
```

I'm able to normalize within the df by using

```
x_var['ave_win_last5'] = (x_var['ave_win_last5']-x_var['ave_win_last5'].mean())/x_var['ave_win_last5'].std()
```

However, when I attempt to then normalize within the group, the output is all NAN

```
x_var['ave_win_last5'] = (x_var['ave_win_last5'] -x_var.groupby('id_race')['ave_win_last5'].mean())/x_var.groupby('id_race')['ave_win_last5'].std()

      ave_win_last5  id_race
0                NaN     6734
1                NaN     6734
2                NaN     6734
3                NaN     6734
4                NaN     6734
```

I'm not sure why this is returning NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `groupby.transform`, and move the normalization logic into `transform`:

```
df['ave_win_last5'] = df.groupby('id_race').ave_win_last5.transform(lambda s: (s - s.mean()) / s.std())

df
#   ave_win_last5  id_race
#0       0.459335     6734
#1      -1.645952     6734
#2       1.033505     6734
#3       0.076556     6734
#4       0.076556     6734
```

Comment: This works for normalizing within the group, however, when I first normalize within the DB then within the group I get the same result as if I just normalized within the group.